# HyperDuo Not Caching

Tags: windows-server-2012, cache

I have purchased a SATA Controller featuring Marvell HyperDuo. However for some reason I am unable to select the ProgramData folder for Caching.

I cannot find any references as to why and have not heard back from any support channels.

I would like to Cache MySQL as I have a large amount of tables being created on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the storage location of MySQLs data folder solved the issue.

Be sure to correct security permissions on the new folder before restarting MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

I had not heard of HyperDuo before now, and after reading their [documentation](https://origin-www.marvell.com/storage/system-solutions/sata-controllers/assets/Marvell-HyperDuo-Technology-Brief.pdf), I now know why - it's a technology solely aimed at the consumer market. Additionally, their list of supported OSes does not include any Windows Server versions.

So - I'd recommend returning this SATA controller and purchasing something that is purpose-built for server workloads - a hardware RAID card that has a large battery-backed write cache will do you well performance-wise, and will be *much* more reliable in the long run.

Comment: The manufacturer website explicitly states support for Windows Sever (http://www.vantecusa.com/en/product/view_detail/578) It's a chipset found in a number of entberprise SATA controllers. I've had great experience with it in other environments until now where I need to Cache ProgramData.

Comment: I suppose I'll have to hope someone with experience with these products will have an answer thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Where are you getting that information? The Marvell page for the HyperDuo controller states explicitly that it is for "...the world’s leading motherboards, home network attached storage (NAS), set-top boxes and desktop HBAs". Nothing about server storage controllers anywhere on the front page, nor in any of the product briefs.

Comment: Link edited in comment